Snowflake Load Tasks to Temporary Table
I want to query tasks using show tasks.  The result from this I want to filter based on data in the name, schedule, or definition columns.  While I can run the show tasks query I can't seem to use the results from the show tasks in a script intended for further processing.  with edf1 as (
show tasks;
)
select * from edf;
with edf1 as (
show tasks;
)
select * from edf;


peer the show tasks with a result_scan: `show tasks;
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));` https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan

thank you - I had to put quotes around the column names but this worked - most appreciated --->
show tasks;  select "name" from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
